# Wordpress: Forcefully logout

Tags: wordpress

When I'm changing the password from front side profile change functionality using "Profile Builder" plugin. Manually i add the logout functionality like below :

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(home_url()); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Then it asking confirmation that you really wants to logged out.

I don't want that confirmation, because it redirects to wp-admin for confimation.

Any way to forcefully logged out from front in wordpress.

Comment: Ideally the link should just log the user out without confirmation. Try disabling the "Profile Builder" plugin and then see if the link will work without confirmation.

Comment: @Anand I want that plugin because in our site we have change profile functionality. When i'm changing the password from change profile then this issue is occured. If i changed the other fields and then logged out it is not asking for confirmation.

Comment: What I was suggesting was just a test to iron out that its not the plugin that is causing the confirmation.

Comment: @Anand yes, i undestand what you say. I deactivate my plugin and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate the plugin and add the following code to functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_after_logout' );

function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();
}
```

Change your link code to

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: I add the above as you commented, but then also it redirects to confirmation page when i click on logout link. Please see [http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ff3u25oc5](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ff3u25oc5)